# data.table subset table multiple conditions

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with the package data table and I'm wondering what the alternative to the vector scan I'm using below would be.

```
x<-data.table(v1=1:30, v2=sample(c("a", "b"), 30, replace=TRUE),
  v3=sample(1:30, 30, replace=TRUE))

x[(x$v2=="a" & x$v3>10) | (x$v2=="b" & x$v3<20),]
```

Thank you, Z

THANKS FOR RESPONSES: I tried them and am not seeing appreciable differences. here are the additional attempts:

```
x<-data.table(v1=1:30000000, v2=sample(c("a", "b"), 30000000, replace=TRUE),
              v3=sample(1:30, 30000000, replace=TRUE))

ptm <- proc.time()
x[(x$v2=="a" & x$v3>10) | (x$v2=="b" & x$v3<20),]
proc.time() - ptm # 4.37

ptm <- proc.time()
x[(v2=="a" & v3>10) | (v2=="b" & v3<20),]
proc.time() - ptm # 4.29


ptm <- proc.time()
rbind(x[(v2=="a" & v3>10)], x[(v2=="b" & v3<20)])
proc.time() - ptm # 5.03

setkey(x, "v2")
ptm <- proc.time()
rbind(x[(v2=="a" & v3>10)], x[(v2=="b" & v3<20)])
proc.time() - ptm # 4.35 (not incl. time of setkey)



setkey(x, "v2")
ptm <- proc.time()
rbindlist(list(x[(v2=="a" & v3>10)], x[(v2=="b" & v3<20)]))
proc.time() - ptm # 3.87 (not incl. time of setkey)


setkey(x, "v2", "v3")
ptm <- proc.time()
dim(x[J(c('a','b'))][(v2 == 'a' & v3 > 10) | (v2 == 'b' & v3 < 20)])
proc.time() - ptm #4.16 (not incl time of setkey)
```

Comment: `data.table` doesn't support indexed conditional scans, as far as I know.

Comment: you don't need the `x$`'s

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this would be faster. Would probably need a bigger test case to test properly, but since you are asking, perhaps you have one:

```
 setkey(x, "v2")
 rbind( x[v2=="a"&v3>10], x[v2=="b"&v3<20] )
```

Comment: perhaps this instead after you set the key: `x[J(c('a','b'))][(v2 == 'a' & v3 > 10) | (v2 == 'b' & v3 < 20)]` - with a large number of elements in `v2` it should make a big difference (assuming this is done more than once per key or `setkey` was already done for a different reason).